# NPM install errors on one machine, not the other

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli, npm-install

I am working on this Angular application for a few months now and it works just find on machine A. No errors (except my own stupid typos).

Next month I am going away for a while so I want to run the Angular application on my laptop. Everything is installed (node, angular, etc). I downloaded the source from the git repository and tried to install the node_modules with *npm i* and this is the result:

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk npm ERR!
> @angular/cdk@"^12.1.0" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the
> upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with
> --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm ERR! See
> C:\Users\MY-USER_Folder\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt
> for a full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\MY_USER_FOLDER\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-31T11_53_25_751Z-debug-0.log

Of course, MY_USER_FOLDER is not the real folder, but I like to remove my username from public websites.

The log is huge, but if needed I can provide it. Maybe someone has a clue with the errors above.

As requested the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ngx-admin",
  "version": "10.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --configuration production --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:coverage": "rimraf coverage && npm run test -- --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint ngx-admin-demo --fix",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "docs": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs",
    "docs:serve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs -s",
    "prepush": "npm run lint:ci",
    "release:changelog": "npm run conventional-changelog -- -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 es5 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points --tsconfig \"./src/tsconfig.app.json\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.12",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "3.0.1",
    "@nebular/auth": "10.0.0",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "10.0.0",
    "@nebular/security": "10.0.0",
    "@nebular/theme": "10.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^14.0.0",
    "angular2-chartjs": "0.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "2.7.1",
    "ckeditor": "4.7.3",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "echarts": "^4.9.0",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.3",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "leaflet": "1.2.0",
    "monaco-editor": "^0.24.0",
    "nebular-icons": "1.1.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "~1.2.9",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-echarts": "^4.2.2",
    "ngx-monaco-editor": "^12.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.0",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "6.6.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.0",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "tinymce": "4.5.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "typeface-exo": "0.0.22",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.10",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.4.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "14.2.12",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/d3-color": "1.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.70",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.2",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "1.3.4",
    "eslint": "^8.23.0",
    "husky": "0.13.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.19",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "stylelint": "7.13.0",
    "ts-node": "3.2.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "^0.9.9",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4"
  }
}
```

Things I tried:

- Google (duh)
- Downgrade and upgrade node and angular (cli)
- Use the npm i --force and npm i --legacy-peer-deps (gives errors)
- Try to update individual packages listed in the errors
- Reviewed the questions already asked on Stack Overflow (no helpful results)

None of these seem to work, otherwise I wouldn't be typing here.

Comment: Fix the upstream dependency conflict - the upstream dependency is shown in the full error log, which you didn't post here, or just use `npm install --force` or `npm install --legacy-peer-deps ` as shown in your post ;)

Comment: @MeerArtefakt Thank you for replying. How do I fix that? I did use the npm install --force, as shown in the "things I tried". I also tried the --legacy-peer-deps, but I forgot to mention it. Will put it in the OP

Comment: Any chance that you checked out a different commit on Machine A than on Machine B? For example because you are on a different branch or forgot to run `git pull`?

Comment: please include `package.json` and extracts from your errors (anything that gives a package and version is a good clue about the conflict). Don't take downvotes personally. Sometimes it can just mean "this won't be helpful to a future user"

Comment: @AndrewAllen Good one. Forgot about the package.json. Added in the OP
Well, I don't take it personally. It just feels a bit stupid.

Comment: @JSONDerulo I am on the same branch and same commit. I double checked after your comment.

Comment: Change your angular cdk version to same as animations or downgrade other angular packages to same as cdk version.

Comment: I get weird issues like this sometimes. In the end, deleting `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` folder, then running `npm install` seems to fix it a lot of the times.  I do not understand why because it's frustrating, but it's certainly worth trying.

Comment: At a minimum you'll need to force install @angular/cdk to match the @angular/core version. For the rest....that's a lot of dependencies! For example `ngx-monaco-editor` only supports up to v10 angular and hasn't been updated in 2 years. Similar issue with `ng2-smart-table`. I suggest digging into each dependency (the release notes of versions if they don't maintain a CHANGELOG.md) to find out which angular version they support and install the relevant version. Won't be easy to fix

Comment: @AndrewAllen I am trying so hard to get the cdk as the same version of the core, but nothing works. I am no Angular expert, I am a C# expert. I want a simple front-end web application that consumes an API. Since I am no designer I use a template: ngx-admin. Maybe this is not the right one, but it works... On one machine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was almost impossible to find the right answer, so I tried something different: work with a different template. This one works on both the laptop and desktop.

Comment: Not getting straight answers on the OP isn't either. But I did say "something" with an explanation. Maybe read the whole story? I said I used a different template that works on both machines since I didn't get the first template to work.